# SQL. how to display missing row in another table?

Tags: sql

I have these tables

```
create table Employee2
( 
     eid char(3), 
     ename char(10), 
     salary number(7,2), 
     mid char(3),

     primary key (eid), 
     foreign key (mid) references Employee2
);

create table ArtObject2 
(
     aoid char(3), 
     atitle char(12), 
     artist varchar(10), 
     pricea number(8,2), 

     primarykey (aoid)
);

create table MakesD2 
(
     aoid char(3), 
     eid char(3), 
     cid char(3), 
     prices number,  
     dates date, 

     primary key (aoid, CID), 
     foreign key (aoid) references ArtObject2, 
     foreign key (CID) references Customer2, 
     foreign key (eid) references Employee2
);
```

This is some sample data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hyDH.jpg

I am trying to find employees who didn't sell a painting with the asking price over 500,000.

Here is what I have so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.ename
FROM Employee2 e 
INNER JOIN MakesD2 md on md.eid = e.eid
INNER JOIN ArtObject2 a on a.aoid = md.aoid
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT md.prices 
                  FROM MakesD2 
                  WHERE a.pricea < 500000);
```

Supposed to get these values

```
Wilson
Loftus 
Smith
Fox
Wolf
Fox
Liy
```

Comment: Don't delete your question if it has been solved. You accepted an answer, **that** marks this question as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT e.ename
FROM Employee2 e
WHERE e.eid NOT IN (SELECT md.eid
                    FROM MakesD2 md
                    INNER JOIN ArtObject2 a 
                      ON a.aoid = md.aoid
                    WHERE a.pricea > 500000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close!

For `[not] exists()` you want to move those joins into the `exists()` subquery, and check the `eid` inside the subquery against the `eid` from the main query; and change `a.pricea<500000` to `a.pricea>500000` since this is `not exists()`.

```
select e.ename
from Employee2 e
where not exists (
  select 1
  from MakesD2 md
    inner join ArtObject2 a 
      on a.aoid = md.aoid
  where a.pricea > 500000
    and e.eid = md.eid
  );
```

Comment: I get these values   Wilson
Jones
Loftus
Wang
Green
Fox
Liu                                                                                                                          However Jones, Wang, and Green sold a painting with a asking price over 500,000